# Operator overloading + with pointer array of class objects C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operator-overloading

I'm working on a small assignment for a class. I need to overload the '+' operator to add together two private member variables of a class object. The class objects are pointed to by an array of class pointers. I'm not quite sure where to start debugging, but my operator overload function causes the program to crash.

Here is main.cpp (ignore printObjects and freeObjects for now).

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;

void createObjects(Foo* fooArr[3], Foo* newFoo);
void printObjects(Foo* fooArr[3], Foo newFoo);
void freeObjects(Foo* fooArr[3], Foo newFoo);

int main()
{
    Foo *fooArr[3] = { 0 };
    Foo *newFoo = 0;
    createObjects(&fooArr[3], newFoo);
    Foo f1 = *(fooArr[1]) + *(fooArr[2]);
    f1.outputX();
}

void createObjects(Foo* fooArr[3], Foo* newFoo)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        newFoo = new Foo(i+1);
        fooArr[i] = newFoo;
    }
}
```

Here is Foo.h:

```
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
private:
    int x;

public:

    Foo();
    Foo(int);
    void setX(int);
    const int getX();
    void outputX();
    Foo operator+(const Foo&) const;
};
```

And finally here is foo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Foo.h"


Foo::Foo(int x_)
{
    x = x_;
}
void Foo::setX(int x_)
{
    x = x_;
}
const int Foo::getX()
{
    return x;
}
void Foo::outputX()
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
Foo Foo::operator+(const Foo& f2) const
{
    Foo f3(0);
    f3.x = x + f2.x;
    return f3.x;    
}
```

The program crashes (segFault), right after calling the operator+ overload function. Now I know this means I am trying to access memory that the program doesn't actually have access to. However, I just don't know how to craft the operator overload statement to work with the function call:

```
 Foo f1 = *(fooArr[1]) + *(fooArr[2]);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Should be `createObjects(fooArray, newFoo)`.

Comment: Should be `createObjects(fooArray)`. Fix the signature of that function.

Comment: Your problem is in the `createObjects()` function and the manner of calling it.    One property of undefined behaviour is that symptoms (such as a program crash) don't always occur immediately - a problem may occur, but the observed symptom occurs later.     The only guarantee is that symptoms occur AFTER the cause, not BEFORE.

Comment: I find it strange that you return `f3.x` and not the object itself in the `operator+` overload

Comment: Why should I remove newFoo from createObjects? Don't I need to pass that class in to the function?

Comment: No, it is redundant, `fooArr[i] = new Foo(i + 1);` is enough

Comment: Ok, got it working. In the call createObjects(fooArray, newFoo), I needed to just change how I was passing the parameters! Can anyone explain exactly why I needed to do that? I feel like I'm missing something basic but important here.

Comment: Passing the address of the 3rd element of `fooArr` would cause you to try access memory that isn't yours

Comment: Duh! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help everyone. Program is now working perfectly!